Create a new document with an embedded form using an automated Lotus Script agent
I have a Notes form which is stored in new documents when they are created.
What I am now trying to do is to generate a new document each week using a LotusScript agent, with the Notes form stored within it, so I can then mail it out to users.
So far, I have managed to get the Agent to create the new document in Notes but it does so without the form stored within it.
If I then edit and save the newly created document, the form is embedded correctly.
Can someone point me in the right direction, on how to get Notes to include the stored form when creating the new document?
The code I have at the moment is as follows:
Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim newdoc As NotesDocument

    Set db=session.currentdatabase
    Set newdoc=db.createdocument

    newdoc.Form= "Executive Summary"

    Call newdoc.save(True,True) 

End Sub

Many Thanks,
Simon

IIRC storing the form with the document is more than just adding a form field.  And it's only done in the UI of the Notes client.  Or at least that's the way it used to be (I'm a retired Notes developer.)

It's been a while... Since the "Store form in document" is a property of the form itself, you may be able to do this by set that property in the Executive Summary form and calling newDoc.ComputeWithForm before you do the save.  If that doesn't work, I think you might have two choices.

Save it, open it up as a NotesUIDocument (which you can't do if this is a server agent) and then use the NotesUIDocument.save method to get the client software to perform the magic for you.

Or...

Mail it to a mail-in database using the attachForm argument of the NotesDocument.Send method. Then either wait for a while and open that database to copy the mailed document to where you really want it, or (probably better) set up an "After mail is delivered" agent in the mail-in database so that it will do the copy operation for you. Either way, though, there's going to be an unpredictable delay while the router does the magic for you.

